# Find the uniform joint cdf of a circle in terms of $R$ and $\Theta$

Tags: statistics

I am having trouble finding the joint cdf of this question:

The pair $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed in a ring centered about the origin and inner and outer radii $r_1 < r_2$. Let $R$ and $\Theta$ be the radius and angle corresponding to $(X, Y)$.

My steps to a solution.

I know that for a uniform distribution the cdf is $\frac{1}{b-a}$. Furthermore, the cdf of $\theta$ is $\frac{\theta}{2\pi-0}$. I can find the denominator for $r$ which is $\frac{1}{r_{2}-r_{1}}$. Would the numerator be $r$?

Comment: The question does not make much sense. cdf of a circle has no meaning. Finding cdf of something in terms of $R$ and $\theta$ also has no meaning since $R$ and $\theta$ are random. Can you rephrase the question?

Comment: $\Theta$ is not well-defined unless you specify the range, which is usually an interval of length $2\pi$ (with two most widely used choice including $(-\pi, \pi]$ or $[0, 2\pi)$). Which convention are you adopting here?

Comment: That is the original question given to me in my assignment. The answer for the cdf is this $\frac{\pi r^{2}-\pi r_{1}^{2}}{\pi r_{2}^{2}-\pi r_{1}^{2}}\cdot \frac{\theta }{2\pi }$

Comment: Also, $R$ is *not* uniformly distributed, as we can check that the c.d.f. of $R$ is given by $$F_R(r) = \begin{cases} (r^2-r_1^2)/(r_2^2-r_1^2), & \text{if }r_1 \leq r \leq r_2, \\ 0, & \text{if } r < r_1, \\ 1, & \text{if } r > r_2 \end{cases}. $$

Comment: My question is why is that the ratio for R from r1 to r2? How did you get 1 for r > r2?

Comment: Recall the definition $F_R(r) = \mathbb{P}(R \leq r)$. By the setting, it is clear that $R$ is supported on the interval $[r_1, r_2]$, i.e., $\mathbb{P}(r_1 \leq R \leq r_2) = 1$. So $F_R(r)=1$ if $r > r_2$. Similar consideration shows $F_R(r)=0$ for $r < r_1$. For $r$ between $r_1$ and $r_2$, the region with $R \leq r$ corresponds to the intersection of the annulus with the disk of radius $r$, hence $$F_R(r)=\frac{[\text{area of the region }r_1^2\leq x^2+y^2\leq r^2]}{[\text{area of the region }r_1^2\leq x^2+y^2\leq r_2^2]}=\frac{\pi r^2-\pi r_1^2}{\pi r_2^2-\pi r_1^2}.$$

Comment: So anytime there is a probability outside of x, y, r, theta, etc. it is 1? To always find the probability of a bound area you subtract the arbitrary bound by the first bound all divided by second bound minus the first bound right? Finally, every time you try to find the joint cdf of two functions it will be both cdf's multiplied by each other?

Comment: For each of three questions, the answer is no. (For Q1, for example we have $\mathbb{P}(R\leq r)=0$ if $r<r_1$. For Q2, it depends on which distribution you are dealing with. For Q3, again it depends on the joint distribution of $(X, Y)$. Indeed, the joint c.d.f. factors into the product of c.d.f. of each variable if and only if the variables are independent. In your specific setting, $R$ and $\Theta$ are independent, but the answer can differ for other distributions of $(X, Y)$.) I recommend you to draw pictures to get some understanding on this problem.